# Not getting JS/CSS filelinks while reloading the page using Angular.js and .htaccess

Tags: javascript, angularjs, .htaccess

I am getting some link failure error while reloading the page using Angular.js and .htaccess. Actually i was trying to remove hash tag in angular.js. I set .htaccess file and set the base href . I am explaining my code below.

> .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /Gofasto/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(css|js|html|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|txt)
    RewriteRule (.*) index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

> loginRoute.js:

```
var Admin=angular.module('Channabasavashwara',['ui.router']);
Admin.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider,$locationProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
    $stateProvider
     .state('/', {
            url: '/',
            templateUrl: 'dashboardview/login.html',
            controller: 'loginController'
        })
        .state('dashboard', {
            url: '/dashboard',
            templateUrl: 'dashboardview/dashboard.html',
            controller: 'dashboardController'
        })
        .state('dashboard.profile', {
        url: '/profile',
        templateUrl: 'dashboardview/profile.html',
        controller: 'profileController'
    })
    .state('dashboard.dept', {
        url: '/dept',
        templateUrl: 'dashboardview/dept.html',
        controller: 'deptController'
    })
    .state('dashboard.princpal', {
        url: '/princpal',
        templateUrl: 'dashboardview/princpal.html',
        controller: 'princpalController'
    })
    .state('dashboard.dept_head', {
        url: '/dept_head',
        templateUrl: 'dashboardview/depthead.html',
        controller: 'deptheadController'
    })
    $locationProvider.html5Mode({
      enabled: true,
      requireBase: true
    });

})
```

when i am in dashboard page its working fine.but when i am in profile page 1st time its working fine and when i am reloading this page again i am getting the following error.

```
failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost/Gofasto/dashboard/controller/profileController.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost/Gofasto/dashboard/controller/deptController.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost/Gofasto/dashboard/controller/deptheadController.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost/Gofasto/dashboard/js/newbill.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
profile:118 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).chosen is not a function
http://localhost/Gofasto/dashboard/css/bootstrap.min.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost/Gofasto/dashboard/css/style22.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost/Gofasto/dashboard/css/plugins.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost/Gofasto/dashboard/css/pace.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost/Gofasto/dashboard/css/style.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost/Gofasto/dashboard/icons/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

All my css and js folders are present inside `Gofasto` folder but it is showing the wrong link where 1st time it is coming properly.I also set `<base href="/Gofasto/">`in the index page.Please help me to resolve this error.

Comment: What are the correct paths of those files?

Comment: @Nerdwood : `http://localhost/Gofasto/css/style.css` this should be the path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using an absolute path when referring to the resources, eg:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Gofasto/css/style.css">
```

... or:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css">
```

... instead of:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
```

Comment: @ Nerdwood : No,i did as per you but the links are not coming at all even from begining.

Comment: Do you have a public version of the website, or just the localhost version? Would be very useful to check it out.

Comment: @ Nerdwood : only localhost.

Comment: Can you please show how you are including the resources (e.g. CSS)?

Comment: @ Nerdwood : `<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/plugins.css" rel="stylesheet">` in this way its coming and problem is happening as per my explanation in post.When i did as per you it was not coming at all.

Comment: You can even try a more absolute reference for the resources - I'll add it to the answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91960/discussion-between-satya-and-nerdwood).